# Typerror: unorderable types

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I'm writing a class for temperatures and I'm trying to compare if temp1>temp2 and so on.

This is part of the code for one of the function definitions that's supposed to handle comparisons.

```
 def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.__valid==True and other.__valid==True:
        if self.__scale==other.__scale:
            if self.__mag==other.__mag:
                return True
            else:
                return False
            #if self.__mag>other.__mag:
                #return True
            #else:
                #return False
            #if self.__mag>=other.__mag:
                #return True
            #else:
                #return False
        else:
            if self.__scale=="C":
                A=other.celsius()
                if self.__mag==A.__mag:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

            if self.__scale=="F":
                B=other.fahrenheit()
                if self.__mag==B.__mag:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False



    else:
        return False
```

But when I do:

```
A=Temperature(37.0, "C")<br>
B=Temperature(30.0, "C")<br>
print(A>B)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\temperature.py", line 218, in <module>
    print(A>B)
TypeError: unorderable types: Temperature() > Temperature()
```

I'm trying to compare the magnitudes of the two but this is an ongoing issue.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the Temperature class?

Comment: Might I suggest making a `.kelvin()` method, with which you can consistently compare any temperatures without having to check what scales are being used? Then your code boils down to `return self.kelvin() == other.kelvin()`

Comment: Of course you can do this with `.celsius()` or `fahrenheit()` just as well, but the sciencey part of me wants to do all comparisons in Kelvin ;)

Comment: Have you defined anything other than `__eq__`?

Comment: I think you should be defining `__lt__(self, other)` if you havent?

Answer (score 5):

`__eq__()` only handles equality tests. You want to define `__le__()` ("≤") and friends.

You can use [`functools.total_ordering()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) in order to automatically define the other inequality operators.

Comment: __le()__ is 'less than or equal to' so is represented by "<=" . "<" uses the __lt()__ method ('strictly less than')

Comment: You can also use [`@functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) instead of an ABC.

Comment: Thanks, this actually makes (way) more sense.